# Google Sign-In that requires ID & Password in Android (without Firebase)

Tags: android

I'm implementing Google Sign-in i android **without** Firebase.

```
Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
```

Above code do automatic sign-in if there are signed-in accounts.
However I want sign-in process that requires ID and password for security purpose(I don't want to know ID and Password).

I've searched the Internet but couldn't find solutions.

```
mGoogleSignInClient.asGoogleApiClient().clearDefaultAccountAndReconnect();
```

I tried above code but it makes an exception.

Is it possible to Google sign-in requiring ID and password for now?

Comment: Why exactly do you need the password? You can get the email if you want using the Google Sign in client

Comment: @edison16029 I want to allow users to some security actions in my app only when they resign-in with ID and password.